# Is it possible to add malayalam font in Midlet programming?

Tags: java-me, fonts, midp

I want to add malayalam font in my programming codes.

But I am not able to find it in midlet programming. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

MIDP defines nothing about fonts. This would be a system-specific extension, so it will depend on which device you're targeting. Normally it's not possible to install new fonts programmatically on these devices.

Comment: any way to display malayalam font in mobile...any suggection or any example will help me...